# How to insert shell variable inside awk command

Tags: linux, shell, variables, awk, variable-assignment

I'm trying to  write a script, In this script i'm passing a shell variable into an awk command, But when i run it nothing happens, i tried to run that line only in the shell, i found that no variable expansion happened like i expected. Here's the code :

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 
  3 # Created By Rafael Adel
  4 
  5 # This script is to start dwm with customizations needed
  6 
  7 
  8 while true;do
  9         datestr=`date +"%r %d/%m/%Y"`
 10         batterystr=`acpi | grep -oP "([a-zA-Z]*), ([0-9]*)%"`
 11         batterystate=`echo $batterystr | grep -oP "[a-zA-Z]*"`
 12         batterypercent=`echo $batterystr | grep -oP "[0-9]*"`
 13 
 14         for nic in `ls /sys/class/net`
 15         do
 16                 if [ -e "/sys/class/net/${nic}/operstate" ]
 17                 then
 18                         NicUp=`cat /sys/class/net/${nic}/operstate`
 19                         if [ "$NicUp" ==  "up" ]
 20                         then
 21                                 netstr=`ifstat | awk -v interface=${nic} '$1 ~ /interface/ {printf("D: %2.1fKiB, U: %2.1fKiB",$6/1000, $8/1000)}'`
 22                                 break
 23                         fi
 24                 fi
 25         done
 26 
 27 
 28         finalstr="$netstr | $batterystr | $datestr"
 29 
 30         xsetroot -name "$finalstr"
 31         sleep 1
 32 done &
 33 
 34 xbindkeys -f /etc/xbindkeysrc
 35 
 36 numlockx on
 37 
 38 exec dwm
```

This line :

```
netstr=`ifstat | awk -v interface=${nic} '$1 ~ /interface/ {printf("D: %2.1fKiB, U: %2.1fKiB",$6/1000, $8/1000)}'`
```

Is what causes `netstr` variable not to get assigned at all. That's because `interface` is not replaced with `${nic}` i guess.

So could you tell me what's wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to `/grep/` with your variable, you have 2 choices :

```
interface=eth0
awk "/$interface/{print}"
```

or

```
awk -v interface=eth0 '$0 ~ interface{print}'
```

See http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Using-Shell-Variables

Comment: Hmm, but what does `/ /` do ?

Comment: // means to `grep` from the input (aka matching)

Comment: to be exact, // in awk means to process only lines matching pattern contained between them, like condition, i.e. only lines matching expression are considered as valid to be processed by awk program. Honestly, I can't remember right now if awk variables can be used as pattern ( or how, if so ), and I happen to be too tired to play with it, however you could try $(...) instead of ``, or maybe expression-enclosings trick ( you can use any character instead of // defining start and end of expression,like %..% or any other.Sort of last resort way is using external file with awk program separately.

Comment: try using "interface" variable somewhere else in awk program, e.g. within printf(),to make sure if it's really variable substitution, or only use of variable inside // matching (reg)expression.

Comment: consider these three simple awk programs: 
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$ ls | awk '/^a/ { print $1;}' 
aa.sh
aaa.sh
azz.jpg

dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$ ls | awk '/^aa/ { print $1;}' 
aa.sh
aaa.sh
       
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$ ls | awk '/sh$/ { print $1;}' 
aa.sh
aaa.sh
dtpwmbp:~ pwadas$

Comment: yup, it's like I thought, awk substitutes variables properly, but between //, inside regex ( or awk regex, depending on some awk parameter AFAIR ), awk variable cannot be used for substitution, like with  ls | awk -v ptrn=aa '/ptrn/ { print $1 ptrn;}' <= this prints ptrn in print, but doesn't use "aa" inside // expression. Good luck, good night :)

Answer (score 2):

> it's like I thought, `awk` substitutes variables properly, but between `//`, inside regex ( or `awk` regex, depending on some `awk` parameter AFAIR), `awk` variable cannot be used for substitution

I had no issue grepping with variable inside an `awk` program (for simple regexp cases):

```
sawk1='repo\s+module2' 
sawk2='@project2\s+=\s+module2$'
awk "/${sawk1}/,/${sawk2}/"'{print}' aFile
```

(Here the `/xxx/,/yyy/` displays everything between `xxx` and `yyy`)
(Note the double-quoted `"/${sawk1}/,/${sawk2}/"`, followed by the single-quoted `'{print}'`)

This works just fine, and comes from "[awk:  Using Shell Variables in Programs](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Using-Shell-Variables.html)":

> A common method is to use shell quoting to substitute the variable’s value into the program inside the script.
>   For example, consider the following program:

```
printf "Enter search pattern: "
read pattern
awk "/$pattern/ "'{ nmatches++ }
     END { print nmatches, "found" }' /path/to/data
```

> The awk program consists of two pieces of quoted text that are concatenated together to form the program.
>
> - **The first part is double-quoted, which allows substitution of the pattern shell variable inside the quotes**.
> - The second part is single-quoted.

It does add the caveat though:

> Variable substitution via quoting works, but can potentially be messy.
>   It requires a good understanding of the shell’s quoting rules (see [Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Quoting.html#Quoting)), and it’s often difficult to correctly match up the quotes when reading the program.